# Show Matplotlib Xaxis labels only at half and full hour

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a matplotlib chart that has a time x axis (timestamps converted by `matplotlib.dates.date2num()`).

I want to show a grid with labels that mark each half and full hour, like this: 10:00, 10:30, 11:00,...

To format the labels intervals I use these code lines:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator(interval=30))
```

The problem is - the data does not start at a full or half full hour. So what I get instead are just the correct intervals, but shifted away from each half and full hour. I.e. 10:17, 10:47, 11:17,... depending on when the data starts. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Can't you set the axes limits?

Comment: The `byminute` argument of the `MinuteLocator` might help: "Mark every minute in byminute; byminute can be an int or sequence. Default is to tick every minute: byminute=range(60)". Just try `[0, 30]`.

Comment: @Evert wouldn't I leave part of the chart data out of the chart if I restrict the axes? Unfortunately, It's not an option to start data display at a full or half full hour.

Comment: @languitar I tried using `byminute` while still using `interval` which gave me the error `ValueError: Invalid rrule byxxx generates an empty set.`. But using byminute=[0,30] as the only argument does the trick! I must be tired, using both arguments does not make sense anyways. Do you want to write an answer? If not, I'll jump in and write one.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `byminute` argument as pointed out by languitar is the right way to go.

This code works:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator(byminute=[0,30])
```

Now only half and full hours will show a label.

I initially tested `byminute`, but did not remove `interval=30`, which results in the error:

> ValueError: Invalid rrule byxxx generates an empty set.

So using the arguments `byminute` and `interval` at the same time does not work and is not necessary anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `MinuteLocator` with just the `byminute` argument:

```
mdates.MinuteLocator(byminute=[0,30])
```

This will fix the locator to every full and half hour.